# Calculating wavelet coherence averaged over a particular frequency band

Tags: python, signal-processing

I'm trying to determine the wavelet coherence between two signals using a Morlet wavelet and a list of equally spaced frequencies. I'd like for the input to be my two signals and scales corresponding to the frequencies. `PyWavelets` and `PyCWT` seem to be the two most common Python tools for wavelet spectral analysis, but I'm struggling to see how to implement either of them for my desired purposes.

For example, suppose I try `PyCWT` and consider two chirp signals:

```
import numpy as np
import pycwt as wavelet
from scipy.signal import chirp

# Five second signal with sampling frequency 1000
fs = 1000
L = 5
t = np.arange(0, L) / fs

dt=t[1]-t[0]

# Two chirp signals
y1=chirp(t, f0=5, f1=25, t1=5, method="linear")
y2=chirp(t, f0=14, f1=7, t1=5, method="linear")

# Interested in frequency band from 5 to 30 Hz in increments of .5. Convert these
# to corresponding 'scales', or 'pseudo-scales' if you like, for the morlet wavelet:

fmin=5
fmax=30
freqs=np.array(np.arange(fmin,fmax,.5))
scales = .8125 / (freqs*dt) # Using central frequency of .8125 for Morlet
```

Here is where I'm stuck. The wavelet coherence command in `pycwt` is given by `wct` (See line 422 at https://github.com/regeirk/pycwt/blob/master/pycwt/wavelet.py), which is defined as

```
def wct(y1, y2, dt, dj=1/12, s0=-1, J=-1, sig=True,significance_level=0.95, wavelet='morlet', normalize=True, **kwargs)
```

Parameters above include

```
#s0: smallest scale of the wavelet
#dj: spacing between discrete scales
#J: number of scales less one
```

However, one of the problems with using this command for my purpose is that by converting frequencies to scales, the scale spacing, `dj`, will not be constant.

So, I'm looking for a way of overcoming this issue..